# Android's Chrome Homepage on Desktop Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, android, google-chrome-extensions, mobile-ui

I really like the integrated stories on the Google Now, and Chrome screens on my Android phone.  Is anyone aware of a site/method to get this in Chrome for the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a similar integration.  The same stories do pop up under the *for you*[1] section of google news.  Unfortunately, there's no integrated way to dismiss read stories, or really many options at all for preferences.

[1] https://news.google.com/foryou